# Modify read-only memory at low overhead

Tags: c, linux, performance, memory, x86-64

Assume that I have a page of memory that is read-only (e.g., set through mmap/mprotect). How do I modify one word (8 bytes) on this page at the lowest possible overhead?

Some context: I assume x86-64, Linux as my runtime environment. The modifications happen rarely but frequently enough so that I have to worry about overhead. The page is read only to protect some important data that must be read by the program frequently against rogue/illegal modifications. There are only few places that are allowed to modify the data on the page and I know all the locations of these places and the address of the page statically. The problem I'm trying to solve is protecting some data against memory safety bugs in the program with a few authorized places where I need to make modifications to the data. The modifications are not frequent but frequent enough so that several kernel-roundtrips (through system calls) are too costly.

So far, I thought of the following solutions:

- mprotect
- ptrace
- shared memory
- new system call

**mprotect**

```
mprotect(addr, 4096, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ);
addr[12] = 0xc0fec0fe;
mprotect(addr, 4096, PROT_READ);
```

The mprotect solution is clean, simple, and straight-forward. Unfortunately, it involves two round trips into the kernel and will result in some overhead. In addition, the whole page will be writable during that time frame, allowing for some other thread to modify that memory area concurrently.

**ptrace**

Unfortunately, ptraceing yourself is no longer possible (as a ptraced-process needs to be stopped. So the solution is to fork, ptrace the child process, then use PTRACE_POKETEXT to write to the child processes memory.

This option has the drawback of spawning a parent process and will result in problems if the tracee uses multiple processes. The overhead per write is at least one system call for PTRACE plus the required synchronization between the processes.

**shared memory**

Shared memory is similar to the ptrace solution except that it reduces the system call. Both processes set up shared memory with different permissions (RW in the child, R in the parent). The two processes still need to synchronize on each write that is then carried out by the parent. Shared memory has similar drawbacks in complexity as the ptrace solution and incompatibilities with multiple communicating processes.

**new system call**

Adding a new system call to the kernel would solve the problem and would only require a single system call to modify one word in the process without having to change the page tables or the requirement to set up multiple communicating processes.

Is there anything that is faster than the 4 discussed/sketched solutions? Could I rely on any debug features? Are there any other neat low-level systems tricks?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you have *read-only* memory, then why do you suppose there is any way at all to modify it?

Comment: Maybe the following would work. Write something to that read only page, and you would get a page fault. Now in the page fault signal handler, make the page write enabled, write to it, and immediately make it read only again.

Comment: If you need to modify the contents, why make it read-only in the first place?  This seems like an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What actual problem is the not-read-only read-only memory supposed to solve?

Comment: How often does code need to modify a word?  Just once?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll add some clarification to the text. The context of the read-only memory area is to protect some data against concurrent modifications/memory safety violations. Legit modifications on the page happen rarely but frequently enough so that I have to care about overhead.

Comment: @pthonic: I know the locations that are allowed to modify the data on the page, so I don't need to catch the page fault (which will cause additional overhead). One option could be to handle the verification of the allowed locations in the page fault handler but that would complicate the kernel-level design.

Comment: @MathiasPayer What OS?  What about handling the `SIGSEGV` that you're going to get when some process tries to modify read-only memory - that will have a large performance impact, too.

Comment: Frankly I guess I don't understand too, if concurrency is what troubles you, copy-on-write or RW lock might help here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I focus on Linux. I want to protect some data from (memory safety) bugs in the program by making it read-only. Unfortunately, I have to modify that data and several calls to mprotect have too much performance overhead. The page fault handler solution I mentioned in my comment above would be a kernel-based solution, not a user-land. If I catch the segfault in user-land, then I still need to use mprotect to change the pages which will result in even higher overhead.

Comment: Given those restrictions, I'd think your best option would be a new system call to update the memory and bypass the page protections.  But I hope whoever implements the kernel changes necessary aren't associated with what's apparently your buggy app.  If they can't get an application's memory access correct, they have no business working on kernel code.  This seems like a case of "Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*" "Well then, don't do *that*."

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle. I was hoping that some similar functionality already exists somewhere through an obscure system call or some other neat hardware trick. Note that the we are developing a mechanism to protect *some* data in arbitrary apps -- not necessarily our apps. See this as a method to protect a subset of data given that a large app will always have bugs. :)

Comment: The overhead is quite high, but I would definitely close the modification race window first. (I would get a new anonymous read-write page via `mmap()`, copy the contents from the read-only page, update the data on the new page, `mprotect()` the new page as read-only, and finally `mremap()` the modified data over the old page.) Performance-wise, I believe that the shared memory approach with a separate manager/writer process (read-only clients requesting modifications via a separate shared memory page per client) would perform best.